# Why does a 401 response trigger this htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-401

Here is the htaccess in the root of the site (simplified)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

What I expect that to do is rewrite anything that is not a directory or file to index.php. And on most servers it works that way.  So, for instance the rewrite rule has no effect on the subdirectory /test.  And if I put a htaccess Auth request in the htaccess file of /test then that works fine.

On this particular server, I do exactly that and the rewrite rule is actioned. Can anybody explain to me why?

Case one - no auth call in subdirectory = no rewriting occurs

Case two - auth call in subdirectory = rewriting occurs and a 404 results.

I am guessing this has t do with how the server is configured to undersstand 401 responses. It seems like the 401 response is being treated like a 404 and so the Rewrite conditions are met.

(Adding a rewrite condition that excludes /test doesn't seem to help either so I am guessing that the 401 response is the issue regardless)

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I am out of my depth here :-) And confused! If anyone has thoughts about why this is then it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is ErrorDocument 401 set to, does the file specified there actually exist & is reachable?

Comment: (And why are you escaping a dot in the substitution part of the rewriterule? That is not a regular expression.)